# Socket.io object doesn't have sockets (is undefined)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Still a noob figuring things out with this, but I'm trying to build a simple real-time chat system.

Here's my main code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs'); //to read contents of client.html
var io = require('socket.io');
// var sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;


var port = 1337; 




var app = express();

app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.get('/', function (request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
        response.end(data);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(port);
io.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message_to_server', function (data) {
        // var sanitizedMessage = sanitize(data["message"]).escape();
        var sanitizedMessage = data["message"];
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client", {message: sanitizedMessage});
    });
});
```

and when I run it, it gives me

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

sure enough I stuck it in the debugger `node debug main.js` and when I checked the value of `io` it seemed like everything was there except for `sockets`

I messed around with it quite a bit and found that`io` is missing `sockets` only when I use `fs` to read a file in my middleware.

so if change my middleware to:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end('this works');
});
```

then `io` has `sockets`, which leads me to believe that it's a timing issue.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sockets` property exists on the return value of the `require('socket.io').listen` function, not on the `require('socket.io')` result itself. Thus, you should do:

```
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on(...);
```